# Java Validation on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, validation

Hello I'm doing a project that requires me to create a program that gathers the users input for a football table which is split into 4 arrays with HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore, Awayscore. and then presented into a specific format. Iv completed this main section but i need to put validation in to prevent the user from typing numbers in the home team and away team and also prventing them from entering nothing aswell as blank spaces.

```
    String[] hometeam = new String[100];
    String[] awayteam = new String[100];
    int[] homescore = new int[100];
    int[] awayscore = new int[100];
    int games = 0;
    String amount = "";
    boolean stop = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of games you wish to list. Type stop to end program and show results");

    amount = keyboard.nextLine();
    int amountconvert = Integer.parseInt(amount);
    String input = "";

    if (amountconvert > 100) {
        System.out.println("The maximum amount of games you can add is 100. Please try again");
        return;
    }

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the HomeTeam:AwayTeam:HomeScore:AwayScore ");

        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            break;
        }

        String[] inputindex = input.split(":");
        if (Integer.parseInt(inputindex[2]) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(inputindex[3]) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Errors found, Please format as shown");
        } else if (inputindex.length == 4) {
            hometeam[games] = inputindex[0];
            awayteam[games] = inputindex[1];
            homescore[games] = Integer.parseInt(inputindex[2]);
            awayscore[games] = Integer.parseInt(inputindex[3]);
            games++;
        }
    } while (games < amountconvert);

    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("*******************************************************************");

    for (int index = 0; index < games; index++) {
        System.out.println("   " + hometeam[index] + " " + "[" + homescore[index] + "]" + " | " + awayteam[index]
                + " " + "[" + awayscore[index] + "]");
    }
    System.out.println("*******************************************************************");
```

I am  beginner at java so any help would be appreciated. iv had a look online and most ways to do it is try/catch and while loops but i cant figure out where they need to be and how to make them loop back

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create a loop around the point where the scanner scans for input, test something about the input, and then start over unless some condition is satisfied (the input is valid). Something like this could replace the do while loop:

```
do {
  System.out.println("Enter the HomeTeam:AwayTeam:HomeScore:AwayScore ");
  boolean stopped = false; // flag to be activated if the user entered stop
  while (true) { // loop to keep getting an input until it is valid
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
      stopped = true;
      break;
    }
    String[] inputIndex = inpit.split(":");
    if (/*Test anything that must be true in order for the input to be valid*/) {
      // do some actions now that the input is correct
      break; // Exit the input loop if the input checks out
    }
    else { // if the input is invalid
      System.out.println("Invalid input. Please use the correct format.");
    }
  }
  if (stopped) { // break out of the outer loop if the user entered stop
    break;
  }
} while (/*Condition to keep adding more entries to the array*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking if the input is correct you can use java regular expression. For example the following function checks whether a String is number or not:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str){
    return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
}
```

Here you can learn more about regular expression:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/